# Magento sends order email to customer, we are not getting notifications

Tags: php, email, magento

Whenever any order is placed magento sends email to the customer saying "thank you for your order" but we are not getting any notification emails for the order.

In the backend, I have configured emails in

```
System -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses<br>
System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails
```

I have also tried setting the "Send Order Comments Email Copy Method" to "Separate Email" instead of "Bcc"

Also, we are unable to receive mails through contact form.

Note: we are using Magento 1.8

Any suggestions how can i solve the problem?

Comment: how about sending emails directly from other email account to your contact email? Maybe your email accout has problems?

Comment: the email account itself is working fine, as if i place the order from that email id i am getting the "thank you for your order" email, but i am not getting a notification email for the same.

Comment: do you have single store or multi store? If multistore maybe your configuration is overwritten? Even if you have single store, check configuration in all scopes.

Comment: i did check all that buddy, we have single store and everything is proper, still nothing is working!

Comment: ok, then next proposition :). Take some gmail account (i prefere this becouse they have no surprises). Set gmail email instead your actual contact email. And check if this work.

Comment: already checked that too :)
its not working :(
regardless of the tld,

Comment: Some servers block sending emails with different "from" field than orginal email. Let examine only contact problem. In configuration>contacts check contact email sender. Then go to configuration>shop address emails and find your contact email sender. And set to him same email address as in contacts. And try it

Comment: Tried it.. not working. 

But this should not be the case, as configuration > contacts is for contact form, the configuration > store emails addresses can have different emails, depending on the purpose!